# How does the JMM deal with a section of code where both the effects of synchronization and volatility occur (and cover for each other)?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, volatile, java-memory-model

Given this example:

```
private volatile int yCounter;

public void incrementYCounter() {
    synchronized (getLockYCounter()) {
        this.yCounter++;
    }
}

public int getYCounter() {
    return this.yCounter;
}
```

Assuming thread A updates `this.yCounter` through `incrementYCounter`, because there is a `synchronized` block, the new value of `this.yCounter` will become visible to all non-A threads as well. However, this guarantee (of visibility) was already made through the volatility of `this.yCounter`. The only reason I have a `synchronized` block in `incrementYCounter` is for preventing race conditions (`synchronized` also guarantees new value visibility, but that's already guaranteed by `volatile`).

Now my question arises: based on my current understanding, given another thread calling `incrementYCounter`, there are two procedures done to guarantee visibility of the new value (the procedure done when exiting `synchronized` block, flushing new values to main memory, and the procedure associated with `volatile`, which is to always write values to main memory). These two procedures do the exact same thing, but it seems to me that both are happening because `synchronized` includes guarantees of `volatile` plus more.

**Is my assumption about what is happening true?** If it is, how can I make it so only one of these procedures is happening (improving performance, while still guaranteeing new value visibility).

**EDIT:** The reason I believe this is not a duplicate is because in some cases I do need both `volatile` and `synchronized`. For example, apart from `incrementYCounter`, if there was a getter for `this.yCounter`, then making `this.yCounter` volatile (and the getter unsynchronized) would work. Now, given another method `incrementYCounter` that must be synchronized for reasons other than memory visibility, I believe I will have duplicate effects of both `volatile` and `synchronized` (due to the reasoning above). My question is whether this is true.

Comment: As an important point of clarification, the synchronized block does _not_ in itself mean that the new value will be visible to all other threads. Without the volatile keyword, those other threads are only guaranteed to see the new value if they also enter a synchronized block, on the same object as the thread A used, and read yCounter from within that block. A happens-before edge is always between two events, and in this case it would be between the release of that lock by A and the subsequent acquisition of that lock by there other threads.

Comment: @yshavit If the other threads do have subsequent acquisition of the lock, because `this.yCounter` is volatile, would there be the duplicate effect I mentioned in the question?

Comment: If you're synchronizing on writes *and* reads, then `volatile` is redundant.

Comment: @shmosel Only the read during the `incrementYCounter` is synchronized, not the getter read (I have now included an example getter in the question).

Comment: Then it still needs to be `volatile`, as yshavit explained. Or you can use `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: @shmosel Yes, so volatile would guarantee the memory visibility. However, when using synchronized in `incrementYCounter`, I only need synchronization to prevent race conditions, not to guarantee memory visibility if a subsequent lock was acquired. That goes back to the original question: since both volatile and synchronized guarantee memory visibility, and I need both in this scenario, is there a duplicate procedure being executed regarding ensuring memory visibility? As for `AtomicInteger`, I would always use that (the question here is about trying to understand the behind the scenes).

Comment: The spec guarantees only the behavior. The actual implementation can be optimized depending on the specific code and environment. It's not possible to say as a rule what CPU instructions will be executed.